# How to download a video from website given direct URL

Tags: java, video

I am currently in the process of developing a Java program that downloads/streams some anime videos:

I want to download the video from:

```
https://animetwist.net/a/swordartonline/25
```

I was able to find the direct link to the video:

```
https://animetwist.net/mount/swordartonline/swordartonline25.mp4
```

but I have no idea how I could download or stream that video from this java application I'm creating. I have no idea where to start and all the questions I find are related to YouTube videos and not other videos.

What I know/have tried:

```
VGet - Only for Youtube/Vimeo only...
Xuggler - I tried but don't understand how I could use it to download videos
```

Any help or a point in the correct direction would be much helpful. I don't exactly understand how it would work. The perfect solution would be something in pure java, but using addons are fine as well.

Sorry if my question is unclear, post a comment below and I'll try to answer it as best I can, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to download a file from a URL you do it like any other file in Java. There are several good options for accomplishing this task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java).